# Can we delete the question about Git hosting providers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109440/best-git-repository-hosting-for-a-commercial-project has significant issues:

1. The information is extremely outdated. The answers are dated 2008-2011.
2. It's hardly more than a list of URLs with subjective and barely reasoned endorsements.
3. Despite its uselessness it appears in Google results which is how I found it. This wastes times and detracts from the perceived value of Stack Exchange search results.

I don't see how anyone could base their decision on this information.

Should we delete this?

Comment: What makes you say they are outdated? Aren't github and bitbucket the two most popular git providers any more?

Comment: The last information that was added is like 6 years old. Even if true nobody can rely on that. And really, it's just a URL that is posted there and the sentence "this one is great!".

Comment: Stack Overflow is precisely *not* the site for such questions and unfounded answers. This one is not a jewel that deserves an exception.

Comment: Can the information be found elsewhere on the web in an easy to find format. I don't think so. Thus I think it is worth keeping. Loosing it looses valuable information. github/bitbucket (the top two answers) are still valuable sites.

Comment: @user000001 GitLab is steadily increasing in popularity

Comment: @LokiAstari Please post that answer so that others can vote on it. Currently there is only an "I agree" post, so users can't really vote on a "I disagree" yet.

Comment: Crappy question, crappy answers. Gone now.

Answer (score 30):

I'm going to go ahead and post the "I agree" answer. Someone else can post the "I disagree" answer if they want.

I agree... this question was locked 4 years ago. Given the huge number of repository hosting solutions and the total inability to edit the question or answers on this post, I really see no value in keeping it around. Even if all of the information on that page is correct today, it will be incorrect eventually.

Based on the ["favoriting" of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/109440/timeline) (which is the only metric I know how to lookup), interest in this question has been steadily waning over the years anyway.